# Open document using command line from another srver

Tags: sharepoint, networking, command-line, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to open a sharepoint library document from another server using the command line.

I can open the document using a browser by entering:

```
    http://srv-sharept/M1Documents/Transmissions/A02003639%20Nut%20Housing%20-%20Nut%20with%20Flats.pdf
```

I can open using windows explorere by entering:

```
    srv-sharept\M1Documents\Transmissions\A02003639%20Nut%20Housing%20-%20Nut%20with%20Flats.pdf
```

But no matter what i try in the command line i cannot open the file.

```
    \\srv-sharept\M1Documents\Transmissions\A02003639%20Nut%20Housing%20-%20Nut%20with%20Flats.pdf
            “The network name cannot be found”

    \\srv-sharept\M1Documents\Transmissions\A02003639%20Nut%20Housing%20-%20Nut%20with%20Flats.pdf”
            “The network name cannot be found”

    “\\srv-sharept\M1Documents\Transmissions\A02003639%20Nut%20Housing%20-%20Nut%20with%20Flats.pdf”
            “The network name cannot be found”

    srv-sharept\M1Documents\Transmissions\A02003639%20Nut%20Housing%20-%20Nut%20with%20Flats.pdf
            “The system cannot find the path specified”
```

I can open documents from my pc using:

```
    \\srv-sharept\M1Documents\Transmissions\A02003639%20Nut%20Housing%20-%20Nut%20with%20Flats.pdf
```

But i cannot from the server. Both servers are windows 2008 R2.

Can anybody advise what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have used wget to pull the file as nobody seems to know why this is happening